# Linux symlink not working

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, wine

I have been trying to do symlink but It does not work. This is all it gives me after I do the command

```
ls -s /mnt/01A3D80750CDAFF9/Steam ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/

dimitri@dimitri-desktop:~$ ls -s /mnt/01A3D80750CDAFF9/Steam ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/
/home/dimitri/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/:
total 1140

4 dosdevices     4 playonlinux.cfg  1044 system.reg     40 user.reg
   4 drive_c       40 playonlinux.log     4 userdef.reg

/mnt/01A3D80750CDAFF9/Steam:
total 1081

   0 dosdevices     1 playonlinux.cfg  1032 system.reg     40 user.reg
   0 drive_c        4 playonlinux.log     4 userdef.reg

dimitri@dimitri-desktop:~$ ls -s /mnt/01A3D80750CDAFF9/Steam ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/
/home/dimitri/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/:
total 1140

   4 dosdevices     4 playonlinux.cfg  1044 system.reg     40 user.reg
   4 drive_c       40 playonlinux.log     4 userdef.reg

/mnt/01A3D80750CDAFF9/Steam:
total 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a softlink use

```
ln -s existing_filename new_link_name
```

not

```
ls -s filename1 filename2 ...
```

---

Update for the skeptical

```
$ pwd
/
$ echo proof > /tmp/ordinary
$ mkdir /tmp/elsewhere
$ ln -s /tmp/ordinary /tmp/elsewhere/link
$ cat /tmp/elsewhere/link
proof

$ ln -s /tmp/ordinary ~/p/link
$ cat ~/p/link
proof
```

---

Update for those grappling with directories

```
$ mkdir d1 
$ echo aaa > d1/a
$ echo bbb > d1/b
$ ln -s d1 d3
$ ls -l d3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rgb rgb 2 Mar 30 17:01 d3 -> d1
$ ls -l d3/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 rgb rgb 4 Mar 30 17:01 d3/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 rgb rgb 4 Mar 30 17:01 d3/b
$ cat d3/a
aaa
```

Comment: All I get is a make link of steam, is that what is suppose to happen?

Comment: @Someone you said *"I have been trying to do symlink"*, now you say *"All I get is a make link of steam"* - but isn't that exactly what you wanted? If not, please explain further (carefully) or give some background to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry I used your way and it working fine. Thanks!